# how to access method of dynamic web project using web service?

Tags: java, web-services

I know the core java only and started to learning J2EE. I have a doubt related to Dynamic Web Project.

Currently I have a Dynamic Web Project, JBOSS server and I have to access methods from it using web service.
I am confused about it and tried the different ways like import the package, import the JAR of it, etc.

But I am not getting how to do it with the help of web service. I also don't know the how to create the web service?

Pls tell me how do I access method from it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can do what you're trying to do with a servlet, then *don't* create a full fledged web service.  A servlet is much easier, much more efficient, and arguably much more portable to a wider range of potential clients.

If, for whatever reason, you can't use a servlet (and you *must*, for whatever reason, create a web service), then consider REST instead of SOAP.

For example:

- [RESTEasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy),  or
- [JAX-RS](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Java+API+for+RESTful+Web+Services+%28JAX-RS%29)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create stub files from a wsdl file on windows OS you can use of "java org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java -o src -s WSDL wsdl_name" by setting the classpath variables
in your batch file with(.bat) extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in apache axis.
http://axis.apache.org/axis/